# DOI problem in chicago.bst

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I use natbib with with bibliographystle chicago. I need to add doi links and added the following in the .bst file:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  boldface
 pages empty$
'skip$
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ format.pages }
{  ", " * pages first.page.number * }
  if$
}
 if$
 doilink
  }
```

and

```
FUNCTION {doilink}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "" }
{ doi empty$
{ skip$ }
{ "\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * }
if$
}
if$
}
```

and

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    doi
    otherentries
}
```

(see the complete file here:https://ufile.io/f8d46).

However, my code simply does not work. I get no dois...

So

```
@article{kahn2000sports,
title={{"The sports business as a labor market laboratory."}},
  author={\textbf{Kahn, Lawrence M.}},
  journal={The Journal of Economic Perspectives},
  volume={14},
  number={3},
  pages={75--94},
  year={2000.},
  publisher={JSTOR},
doi= {10.1257/jep.14.3.75}}
```

results in[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a full MWE.

Comment: Why did you name the first function `format.vol.num.pages`? Shouldn't it be `format.jour.vol`?

Comment: Furthermore, it appears you've modified the function `output.nonnull` in some significant ways -- but haven't mentioned it it your write-up. Lots of warning and error messages being issued as a result. Please fix those ASAP.